# Monodevelop for Sharepoint on Linux

Tags: sharepoint-server, linux

I have a Linux machine, with a Sharepoint virtual machine, the virtual machine runs Sharepoint and visual studio.

It currently works, but the question is, would it be possible to get it working with MonoDevelop from the Linux host, to the Sharepoint server in the virtual machine?